# Ориентация экрана в Android

Tags: java, android

Можно ли как то запретить смену ориентации в приложении на устройствах с экранами меньше 7 дюймов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум есть метод [`setRequestedOrientation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29). Вы можете его вызывать в `onCreate` ваших `Activity`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     if(если экран меньше 7 дюймов)
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```